# How to best structure a page flow in mocha test using webdriver.io & selenium?

Tags: node.js, selenium, mocha.js, webdriver-io

I want to test an ecommerce application using  mochajs, webdriver.io & selenium server. Let's take checkout as an example and let's say I want to automate the testing of multiple variations. The most straight-forward approach would be to do something like

```
describe('Checkout', function(){
    it('should be possible to place an order',function(){...});
    it('should be possible to place an order using PayPal',function(){...});
    ...
});
```

The downside here is that if something goes wrong you can only see the failing case which can be relatively complex as you have to go though a lot of steps to place an order. Therefore I was thinking of something like

```
describe('Checkout', function(){
    describe('Place an order',function(){
        it('should show a product page', function(){...});
        it('add a product to cart', function(){...});
        ...
    });
    ...
});
```

So basically I'm misusing `it` to segment my test into pages, that way I can see where something breaks. However if you imagine 10 tests like this it will be a lot of "tests" with a lot of redundancy.

My question now is if there are any best practices or production experiences on how to address this (I assume what I'm trying to do is pretty basic) as we are now at a point where we can still adjust the approach.

Any feedback would be much appreciated.

Comment: As you already know, `describe` will re-launch the browser with a new session and `it` will start the test at the point where the previous test ended.

In my opinion, this is fine.

Comment: We can try one large `it` block with multiple `expect` assertions. If the failure stracktrace is detailed enough, we can write our tests in such fashion, thereby sparing ourselves from writing multiple `it` lines.

Comment: @Noffica, that's how we refactored it now. It makes the tests concise and you need to check the error messaging to find the issue. You can still assert something on every page to get some better tracking within one 'it'

Comment: The advantage of using multiple `it` blocks, though, is that the passing status of each one is reported explicitly in the command-line.

Comment: Yes, that is true but you also end up with an incredible number of tests that are even partly duplicates.

Comment: How do you have partial duplication?

Comment: Because you will always add a product to cart, go to checkout etc.